# How to Deploy a docker container with volume in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, .net-core, google-cloud-run

I am trying to publish an application I wrote in .NET Core with docker and a mounted volume. I can't really figure out or see any clear solution to my issue that will be cheap (Its for a university project.)

I tried running a [docker-compose via a cloudbuild.yml linked in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157940/how-to-deploy-container-using-docker-compose-to-google-cloud) with no luck, also tried to put my dbfile in a firebase project and tried to access it via the program but it didn't work. I also read in the GCP documentation that i can probably use Filestore but the pricing is way out of budget for me. I need to publish an SQLite so my server can work correctly, that's it.

Any help would be really apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't mount volume in Cloud Run. It's a stateless environment and you can't persist data on it. You have to use external storage to persist your data. See the [runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract)

WIth the 2nd execution runtime environment, you can now mount [Cloud Storage bucket with GCSFuse](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse), and [Filestore path with NFS](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I will consider implementing the 2nd execution runtime environment for my project. 

Thank you a whole lot!!!